# How is the shrinkwrap file generated?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap

When locking down node modules using shrinkwrap, how is the npm-shrinkwrap.json file generated? Does it recursively check node_modules folder and get it's info there?

I'm asking because I did a npm install successfully behind a proxy which translated github repo's to an internal artifactory repo, but the generated shrinkwrap contains urls directly to github (what I don't want)

Comment: If the proxy is doing "magical" substitution of those repositories for you, then i would guess that shrinkwrap has no way to deduce the "real" repo urls, but of course they would still work as long as you're behind the proxy?

Concerning your actual question, i think it does what you describe by default but not 100% sure.. Is it not described in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

write ***npm shrinkwrap*** in your terminal folder which contains package.json file which will genrate npm-shrinkwrap.json file

Ya this will check recursively in your node module folder of directory.